# Gnuplot: How to fill up available space in interactive terminal?

Tags: gnuplot, zooming

I am making 3d plots with gnuplot, and I would like to be able to examine them closely.  Here is what a typical image looks like when I use splot:

[image]

As you can see, there is a great deal of white space all around this image (I have colored it in red pen so you can see what whitespace I am referring to.  Next, I try to use `Ctrl+MouseWheel` to zoom in so that I can take a closer look, but instead of enlarging the image, this zooms the data set inside of the rectangular cuboid viewing box.  See the image below for an example of what I mean.

[image]

So the data set is zoomed, but I still have all of that surrounding whitespace on all sides of the image.  How can I zoom the image to fill the available space on my screen?  I am using whatever the default terminal is when you do an splot from the gnuplot command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  I was using `set view equal xyz` to get an orthographic projection with all of the axes scaled equally.  This was causing the whitespace.  You can still use it by scaling the size up with the command `set view ,,2.0` e.g. for a double large scale.  This makes the whole plot larger, bounding box and all.

Answer (score 0):

The primary whitespace is that 'lower' section in the z-direction that gnuplot automatically places in 3-D plots so that you can actually (mostly) see the coordinates. You can place it where you want with:

```
set xyplane #
```

If you are hoping to fill the plot window, also look into setting the terminal dimensions with `set terminal.....`, look at all the margin commands, and possibly set sample # commands.

Comment: Are you talking about the extra whitespace in the bounding cuboid?  Because i was referring to the extra whitespace in the actual Window that contains the plot.  I will edit my image to show you what I mean.

Comment: That is peculiar, when I drag the window bigger, the plot gets bigger. Can you post the commands you use to get that figure?

Comment: Thanks for asking what commands I was using.  That helped me figure it out!